# Identification of Insect found on beach in Maharashtra

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: The Bug was found in Sindhudurga taluka, Maharashtra, on a beach. Morning 0830 hrs] Six legs, two antennas, Neon green colour pattern with black. Had no wings.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a Lychee Shield Bug, Commonly found in India, formerly considered a beetle, but now classified as a True Bug.

Comment: You should add some more details, maybe with some authentic images, to support your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Lychee Shield Bug, *Chrysocoris stolli*, also known as jewel bugs or metal shield bugs. See this picture from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutelleridae):

[image]

Some more information can be found [here](http://sinobug.tumblr.com/post/39343034147/lychee-shield-bug-chrysocoris-stolli) and [here](http://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/show/273206).

Comment: What's wrong with the answer?

Comment: Probably that the question was already answered, only without picture and link.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge Since I don't think the other answer is very good (neither referenced, nor has it an image) I decided to write another one. And I don't expect it to get better, as it is now four weeks old.